# Add Extra criteria to Interactive Report Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I need to add extra parameter to the interactive report for searching criteria. and I need it to be processed when I press the Go button in the interactive report. what I have is the text box but when searching the values entered never reflects in the report when I press the Go button. Any Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a text item, e.g. :P1_SEARCH, you can refer to it in the query in your interactive report, e.g.

```
SELECT ...
FROM   mytable t
WHERE  INSTR(UPPER(t.mycolumn), UPPER(:P1_SEARCH)) > 0;
```

To have the report pick up the value whenever it is refreshed (e.g. from the Go button), make sure to add the item name to the **Page Items to Submit** attribute, i.e. `P1_SEARCH`.

Comment: this is working perfectly with a button that submit the page. However, I wish i could do this through the "Go" button in the IRR , and this is not working

Comment: updated answer - I think you just need to set Page Items to Submit.